# Flutter In App Purchase IOS productDetailResponse.productDetails.isEmpty only in sandbox mode

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

I am able to test my IAP successfully using https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase
in the simulator using storekit.

However, when I try to test on my device in sandbox mode, the products I setup in in App Store Connect are not showing.

`productDetailResponse.productDetails.isEmpty` is indeed empty in sandbox mode.

**FYI** my developer account with Apple has all agreements signed, and it is "Active" under `Paid Apps`

Here is my product:
[image]

I have even debugged `import 'package:in_app_purchase_storekit/in_app_purchase_storekit.dart';` and not seeing any errors.

1. Does it matter that it is in `Drafts`?
2. Does it matter that it is `Ready to submit` ?
3. If not, then what could the issue be?

There is nothing in the logs giving any clues.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Solved. Needed to disable storekit testing in the scheme so it is "None"

See
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/setting-up-storekit-testing-in-xcode

Comment: Hey.. my IAP products are also in `Ready to Submit` state on AppStore connect. I have removed storekit config from scheme as well. But still when I try to fetch product details via `queryProductDetails` method. I get zero products. What could be I missing here?